# Android Client/Server Socket client not receiving

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

I am at this with ages and the problem i am having is simple i am not able to print out the data from the server to client everything else is working just that when the server sends a message to the client the phone it never gets or prints it out any insight or help would be  great and i am getting no errors

client

```
        package com.example.handy;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import android.R.integer;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.text.format.DateFormat;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {

        private EditText ipaddress;
        private Button connect;
        private Button wipe;
        private static String myIp;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
            ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 



            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ipaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipaddress_felid);

            connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
            wipe =(Button) findViewById(R.id.wipe);



            //Button press event listener
            connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                 {
                     setMyIp(ipaddress.getText().toString());
                    // myComs.sending_data(getMyIp() , "Got connected");
                    try
                     {
                        new Incomingdata().execute();
                        InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(getMyIp());
                        Socket s = new Socket(inet, 2000);
                        OutputStream o = s.getOutputStream();
                        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(o);





                         p.println("You are connected");
                         p.flush();

                         readContacts();
                         readSms();




                     }



                     catch (UnknownHostException e) 
                     {
                        ipaddress.setText("Unknown host");
                           e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                 }


             });
            wipe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                 {
                    String kill = "5";
                     myComs.sending_data(MainActivity.getMyIp(), kill);
                     finish();

                 }
                 });
        }
    public class Incomingdata extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            try
            {   System.out.println("Test123");
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2000);
                Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Test1234");
                InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
                Scanner r = new Scanner(in);
                System.out.println("Test1235");
                while(s.isConnected())
                {
                    String input =r.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Client"+input);
                }
                in.close();
            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e) 
            {
                ipaddress.setText("Unknown host");
                   e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }



}
```

Server

```
    package handy_server.simple_gui;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


//imports for server
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Pandaboy
 */
class ServerGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private Socket connection;
    private InetAddress ip;
    private JTextField t1 = new JTextField(null);
    private JTextField t2 = new JTextField(null);
    private JTextField t3 = new JTextField(null);
    private JButton b2 = new JButton("Send");
    private JButton b1 = new JButton("Working");

    private JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    private ServerSocket listeningSocket;
    private int port= 0;
    private ArrayList<Contact> myContacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

      //-------------------------serverGui------------------------------------------------------------
    public ServerGUI(int port){
        this.port = port;
        init();

    }
    public  void init()
    {

        Container content = getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Font f = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 20);
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        content.add(p1);
        p1.add(t1);
        p1.add(b1);
        p1.add(t2);
        p1.add(t3);
        p1.add(b2);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
         b2.addActionListener(this);
        setSize(210, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Just about to start the server...");
        startServer();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object target = e.getSource();
        if (target == b1)
        {

            t1.setText("Button working");
            MyHelpers.buildConversations(this, myContacts);
        }

        if(target == b2)
        {
              t1.setText("button working2");
            String number = t2.getText();
            int phone_length = number.length();
            if (phone_length <= 20)
            {
                for(int a=1; a <=(20 - phone_length); a++ )
            {
                    number += " ";
            }
            }
            String msg = t3.getText();
            String text = "7"+number+msg;
            System.out.print(""+text);
             OutputStream o = null;
            try
            {
                o = connection.getOutputStream();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(o);
            p.println(text);
            p.flush();
            System.out.print("text sent"+text);




        }
    }
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //------------------------------startServer------------------------------------------------------------
    private void startServer() 
    {
        SwingWorker <Void, String> runningServer = new SwingWorker<Void, String>(){
            protected Void doInBackground() 
            {
                System.out.println("in startserver...");
                try 
                {
                    listeningSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                    try
                    {
                        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                        System.out.println("Please enter this in your phone " + ip.getHostAddress());

                    }
                    catch (UnknownHostException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    while (true)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
                        connection = listeningSocket.accept();


                        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                        Scanner r = new Scanner(in);
                        OutputStream o = connection.getOutputStream();
                        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(o);

                        String message = r.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("" + message);
                        t1.setText(message);

                        // get the message type
                        // 0 sms 1 contact 2 incoming call 
                        System.out.println(message);
                        if(message.startsWith("0"))
                        {
                            System.out.println(message);
                            String type = message.substring(1,2);
                            int theType = Integer.parseInt( type );
                            String number = message.substring(7, 21).trim();
                            String theText = message.substring(21);
                            String theName = MyHelpers.getName(number, myContacts);
                            System.out.println("Number = "+number);
                            System.out.println("Sender = "+theName);
                            System.out.println("Text = "+theText);
                            Contact cRef = MyHelpers.getContactReference(number, myContacts);
                            if (cRef != null)
                            {
                                cRef.addsms(theType, theName, theText);
                            }
                        }    



                        if(message.startsWith("1"))
                        {
                           System.out.println(message);
                          String name = message.substring(1, 31).trim();
                          String pnumber = message.substring(31, 51).trim();
                          String email = message.substring(51, 91).trim();

                          myContacts.add(new Contact(name, pnumber, email));
                          System.out.println( name + pnumber + email);  
                        }

                        if(message.startsWith("2"))
                        {
                           String unkown = message.substring(0, 1).trim();

                           String number = message.substring(1, 14).trim();
                           String theName = MyHelpers.getName(number, myContacts);
                           System.out.println(""+unkown+""+theName+" Is calling you");
                        }
                        if(message.startsWith("5"))
                        {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
```

Any Help would be great i am stumped by this

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: No None at all that is why i a bit lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your server append '\n' to the end of the response so change this

```
 PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(o);
            p.println(text);
            p.flush();
            System.out.print("text sent"+text);
```

to this:

```
 PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(o);
            p.println(text + "\n");
            p.flush();
            System.out.print("text sent"+text);
```

i think the reason it hangs is because readLine() is looking for '\n' and it never recieves it

```
while(s.isConnected())
{
    String input =r.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Client"+input);
}
```